# cluster points of sub-sequences of sequence $\frac{n}{e}-[\frac{n}{e}]$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

what is the set of all cluster points of sub-sequences of sequence $\frac{n}{e}-[\frac{n}{e}]$ in which e is Euler's number 2.7182818284590452353602874713527...?

Comment: Since $e$ is irrational, the sequence $$a_n=\left\{\frac{n}{e}\right\}=\frac{n}{e}-\left[\frac{n}{e}\right]$$ is dense in $[0,1]$. That doesn't necessarily apply to every subsequence, $a_{n!}$ isn't dense (the only cluster points are $0$ and $1$).

Comment: Do you define "cluster point" as "limit of some subsequence", or something else?

Comment: what is the meaning of cluster point?

Comment: [Types of limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) "Accumulation point" would be another word for it.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha:=1/e$ is irrational. Hence the sequence of fractional parts 
$
\left(\{n\alpha\}: n\ge 1\right)
$ 
is equidistributed in $[0,1]$. So, the set of clusters (ordinary accumulation points) is still the whole interval $[0,1]$.

We can prove something stronger. Let $\Gamma_x$ be the set of *statistical cluster points*, i.e., the set of all $y$ such that 
$$
S_\varepsilon:=\{n: |x_n-y|<\varepsilon\} 
$$
has not asymptotic density zero for all $\varepsilon>0$, which means $\frac{|S_\varepsilon \cap [1,n]|}{n} \not\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. (Clearly, this is a subset of the ordinary accumulation points.) However, in this case, it is still true that $\Gamma_x=[0,1]$.